# Only allowed to use three variables for truth table however, I feel like I need four.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question states, "**Use truth tables to determine whether the following argument (logical
consequence) is correct – show your work.**

- Premise 1. If Achilles is human then he is mortal.
- Premise 2. If Achilles is not mortal then at least one of his parents is not mortal.
- Conclusion. If both of Achilles’ parents are mortal then Achilles is human.

Note: you must use appropriately the following three variables (**and no others**): hu, mo, pa."

I would set hu = is human, mo = is mortal, and pa = is a parent. However, my question arises where I have to differentiate between two parents. Can someone help me set up my truth table or variables?

Thank you.

Comment: Your "pa" is wrong: none of the statements in this argument say anything about whether or not "Achilles is a parent".

Comment: @MishaLavrov How would I use "pa" when stating at least one of his parents vs both parents?

Comment: "At least one of his parents" and "both of his parents" are not statements by themselves. "Both of Achilles' parents are mortal" is a statement, so let that be "pa". You can express the other claim about Achilles' parents in terms of "pa".

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you, and one last question, if both parents are mortal which is now my pa, would the ~pa account for at least one of his parents?

Comment: Yes: the negation of "Both parents are mortal" is "At least one parent is not mortal".

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you

Comment: Following @MishaLavrov's suggestion: Premise 1 is: $Hu \to Mo$, while Premise 2 is: $\lnot Mo \to \lnot Pa$. The purported conclusion will be: $Pa \to Hu$.